# ElasticSearch term query returns 0 hits although document exists

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, resthighlevelclient

I have an ES domain, from which when I query with the document's `emailId` field, I'm not getting any hits. However this field and value exist for a document. For the same document, querying by `employeeId` works.
Below is how my index mapping looks like.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "employeeId": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "emailId": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is how I'm running the search.

```
public SearchResponse searchForExactDocument(final String indexName, final Map<String, Object> queryMap)
            throws IOException {
        BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        queryMap.forEach((name, value) -> {
            queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(name, value));
        });
        return this.executeSearch(indexName, queryBuilder);
    }

private SearchResponse executeSearch(final String indexName, final QueryBuilder queryBuilder) throws IOException {
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices(indexName);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        return restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

I ran the SearcRequest.source().toString() and below is the source string for the search I get.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "emailId": {
              "value": "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com",
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

below is the document that should get returned, but not getting any hits.

```
index{
  [
    person
  ][
    _doc
  ][
    null
  ],
  source[
    {
      "firstName": "MyEmployee",
      "lastName": "June6Test7",
      "emailId": "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com",
      "employeeId": "13908528"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm finding it very weird that query with `employeeId` works fine but `emailId` won't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Following is my index creating method.

```
public CreateIndexResponse createIndex(final CreateIndexInput createIndexInput) throws IOException {
        CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(createIndexInput.indexName());
        Settings.Builder settingsBuilder = Settings.builder();
        settingsBuilder.put(NUMBER_OF_SHARDS_KEY, createIndexInput.numOfShards());
        settingsBuilder.put(NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, createIndexInput.numOfReplicas());
        settingsBuilder.put("analysis.analyzer.custom_uax_url_email.tokenizer", "uax_url_email");
        createIndexInput.mapping().ifPresent(mapping ->
                createIndexRequest.mapping(mapping, XContentType.JSON));
        createIndexRequest.settings(settingsBuilder.build());
        return restHighLevelClient.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Term query returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field. You need to add .keyword to the emailId field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the emailId field).

By default `text` type field uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. This will break "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com" into the following tokens

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "21june6lambdatest7",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "gmail.com",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "emailId.keyword": {                // note this
              "value": "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com",
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**
Based on the comments below, modify your index mapping and settings as

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "emailId": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "emailId": "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67823510",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "emailId": "21june6lambdatest7@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with this. So to do this from RestHighLevelClient Java library, would it make sense to do something like this?  `Settings settings =
        Settings.builder()
        .put("analysis.analyzer.custom_uax_url_email.type", "custom")
        .put("analysis.analyzer.custom_uax_url_email.tokenizer", "uax_url_email")
        .build();`

Comment: or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @AnOldSoul when you are querying on email id, it is always better to use UAX URL email tokenizer --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html Shall I provide you a working example of the same ?

Comment: Got it, could you point me in the direction of I could use UAX URL email tokenizer with my Java method for search?

Comment: @AnOldSoul you need to define an analyzer(with this tokenizer) in your index settings, and then use this defined analyzer in your index mapping for the `emailId` field. Please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I updated the question with how I'm creating the "person" index now. However the search method is still failing to find the email. I do not pass the mapping explicitly, its created when I index the 1st document. Should I create the mapping explicitly as well? :(

Comment: @AnOldSoul if you have not passed the index mapping explicitly, then I think using `.keyword` will do the trick. Have you tried this as given in the first part of the answer ?

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how I could pass `.keyword` to the source because its being generated through the Java method `executeSearch()` above in the question. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how I could update SearchRequest to include this `.keyword`

Comment: @AnOldSoul can you please accept the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :-)

Comment: Sorry I'm still struggling to figure out how I could use "keyword" with the RestHighLevel Client Java implementation. Is this something you might know?